# Truncate string on last occurrence of any whitelisted character

Tags: php, regex, replace, truncate

I would like use of regex to remove string after some special symbols on last occurrence. i.e. I am having string

```
Hello, How are you ? this, is testing
```

then I need output like this

```
Hello, How are you ? this
```

and these will be my special symbols `, : |`

Comment: share your code what you tried

Comment: share the regex code you tried

Comment: The regexp should match one of the special symbols, followed by any number of characters that are not in that set, followed by the end of string.

Comment: `\b[,); +]+.*$` i tried this but i am not getting string after occurences i need string before occurence of special character

Comment: i think you want to check last occurance of that characters and remove everything after that?isn't it?

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why bother with a regex when normal string operations are perfectly fine?
EDIT; noticed how it not behave correctly with both `:` and `,` in the string.
This code will loop all chars and see which is last and substring it there. If there is no "chars" at all it will set $pos to strings full lenght (output full $str).

```
$str = "Hello, How are you ? this: is testing";
$chars = [",", "|", ":"];
$pos =0;
foreach($chars as $char){
    if(strrpos($str, $char)>$pos) $pos = strrpos($str, $char);
}
if($pos == 0) $pos=strlen($str);
echo substr($str, 0, $pos);
```

https://3v4l.org/XKs2Z

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to split string (by special characters) into an array and remove the last element in array:

```
<?php
$string = "Hello, How are you ? this, is testing";
$parts = preg_split("#(\,|\:|\|)#",$string,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$numberOfParts = count($parts);
if($numberOfParts>1) {
    unset($parts[count($parts)-1]); // remove last part of array
    $parts[count($parts)-1] = substr($parts[count($parts)-1], 0, -1); // trim out the special character
}
echo implode("",$parts);
?>
```

Comment: Keep in mind, this fails if there is no "special chars" in string. https://3v4l.org/oBIlJ

Comment: Very good point thank you for pointing that out. I've just edited the code to include a check on the number of elements in the split array.

Comment: No problem. Just in case you want to clean the code, you can look in to `end()` function instead of count-1

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace()` is best suited for this task -- it is a single native function call that doesn't need to use a loop or generate a temporary array.

Seek one of the listed characters, then check that none of the remaining characters in the string are in that same list -- this is how you know you found the last occurring listed character.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/fNrGM))

```
echo preg_replace('/[,:|][^,:|]*$/', '', 'Hello, How are you ? | this, is testing');
```